# Python: Error identifying time period (morning, evening, etc) from datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the time data (from trip data):

```
df_time[['timestamp_start', 'timestamp_end']].head()

>>
    timestamp_start         timestamp_end
0   2021-06-15 17:49:57.828 2021-06-15 18:14:19.437
1   2021-06-12 08:41:19.846 2021-06-12 08:43:34.794
2   2021-06-15 16:18:40.000 2021-06-15 16:23:50.721
3   2021-06-09 17:15:51.000 2021-06-09 17:17:07.887
4   2021-06-15 16:40:03.375 2021-06-15 17:00:23.050
```

which I convert from object to datetime by doing:

```
# Convert from object to datetime
df_time['timestamp_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_time['timestamp_start'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
df_time['timestamp_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df_time['timestamp_end'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

I would like to plot the counts of pick-ups and drop-offs by time period (i.e. morning, mid-day, evening, and late-night).

For that, I first use the function:

```
def get_time_period(timestamp):
    
    if timestamp >= datetime.time(4, 0, 1) and timestamp <= datetime.time(10, 0, 0):
        return 'morning'
    
    elif timestamp >= datetime.time(10, 0, 1) and timestamp <= datetime.time(16, 0, 0):
        return 'mid-day'
    
    elif timestamp >= datetime.time(16, 0, 1) and timestamp <= datetime.time(22, 0, 0):
        return 'evening'
    
    elif timestamp >= datetime.time(22, 0, 1) or timestamp <= datetime.time(4, 0, 0):
        return 'late-night'
```

and apply it by doing:

```
df_time['pickup_time_period']=df_time['timestamp_start'].apply(lambda x :get_time_period(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").time()) )
df_time['dropoff_time_period']=df_time['timestamp_end'].apply(lambda x :get_time_period(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").time()) )
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .828000
```

When double-checking, my data has been converted to datetime so I don't understand where this might be coming from...

```
df_time[['timestamp_start', 'timestamp_end']].info()

>>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 425 entries, 0 to 424
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------           --------------  -----         
 0   timestamp_start  425 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 1   timestamp_end    425 non-null    datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2)
memory usage: 6.8 KB
```

First I thought that I should change the format when calling the function from "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" to "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f" but when doing this I get an error saying that "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f" is not the right format.

How can I identify the error and make this work?

Source code: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/exploratory-data-analysis-of-nyc-taxi-trip-duration-dataset-using-python-257fdef2749e

Comment: You have already converted your timestamp columns to datetime, why are you trying to parse them again? Apply `get_time_period` to the converted columns directly.

Comment: Instead of comparing to datetime.time, consider using the `.dt.hour` attribute of your datetime columns.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
def get_day_period(x):
    if x in range(6,12):
        return 'Morning'
    elif x in range(12,16):
        return 'Afternoon'
    elif x in range(16,22):
        return 'Evening'
    else:
        return 'Late night'


df_time['day_period_start']=df_time['hour_start'].apply(get_day_period)
df_time['day_period_end']=df_time['hour_end'].apply(get_day_period)
```